# Populating a dropdown list using knockout and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am populating a drop down list using ajax like so.

```
    var getCertifications = function () {
    $.getJSON("/Provider/GetCertifications", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var certification_data = "<option value=" + item.CertificationID + ">" + item.Certification + "</option>";
            $(certification_data).appendTo("#certification");
          });
      });
   };
```

getCertifications is being called in the document.ready method.
I wanted to populate a second drop downlist based on the value of the selected option in the first dropdownlist.So I wrote another function

```
 var getSpecializations = function () {
var value = $("#certification").val();
$.getJSON("/Provider/GetSpecializations/", { certificationID: value }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        var specialization_data = "<option value=" + item.SpecializationId + ">" + item.Specialization + "</option>";
        $(specialization_data).appendTo("#specialization");
          });
      });
  }
```

The html is as shown

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Certification: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="certification",name="certification",data-bind="value: certification" >
                    <option value="0">Select a Certification</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Specialization:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="specialization" , name="specialization" data-bind="value: specialization" >
                    <option value="0">Select a Specialization</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My view model has the observables as shown

```
self.certification = ko.observable("");
self.specialization = ko.observable("");
```

I am calling the getSpecializations function in the subscribe method of the first dropdown like so

```
self.certification.subscribe(function () { 
    getSpecializations();      
});
```

There are no errors in the console ,but the second drop down i.e; the Specializations dropdown is not getting populated.Could you folks point me in the right direction.

Comment: that's because you are trying to push rather assigning . do like this `self.yourarray([//data])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to do like this

**View :**

```
<select data-bind="options:specializationArray,optionsText:'Specialization',optionsValue:'SpecializationId',value:specialization" />
```

**ViewModel:**

```
 var getSpecializations = function () {
var value = self.
$.getJSON("/Provider/GetSpecializations/", { certificationID: value }, function (data) {
   self.specializationArray(data) //array with Specialization and SpecializationId
  }
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/22514/)**

Comment: I just have a followup question because I think it might be causing an issue.Tge data I am receiving from the controller is in the proper JSON format like so   [
  {"CertificationID":1,"Certification":"M.B.B.S."},
  {"CertificationID":2,"Certification":"M.D."},
  {"CertificationID":3,"Certification":"R.N."},
  {"CertificationID":4,"Certification":"M.S.N."}
]
But the data within getJSON looks like this.
[Object, Object, Object, Object].
This looks like an array of objects.Could that be creating an issue.In your fiddle,you are using JSON data to initialise the arrays and not an array of objects.

Comment: Check this how to do using arrayMap . http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/c0y832bc/13/ . cheers

Comment: Am i right in saying that they are an array of objects though.I am a noob in javascript and any technology related to the client side.It kinda looks like this though Array[4]
0: Object
Certification: "M.B.B.S."CertificationID: 1
1: Object
Certification: "M.D."CertificationID: 2
2: Object
Certification: "R.N."CertificationID: 3
3: Object
Certification: "M.S.N."CertificationID: 4
length: 4

Comment: so that fiddle solves your issue or we back to square one . see client side is all about debugging try console.log(//your stuff) and check browser console . `.arrayMap(data , function(item){ console.log(item.CertificationID` what you got in console window now

Comment: you should have your code inside success of ajax call even its async it wont matter . different file (you mean different js) so be it no problem you should refer properly . say ex: if function build() in different js file in current js file we can access it `new build` .

Comment: It looks like ko.utils.map is doing the same thing as $.getJson was doing.Both seem to be giving an array of objects.Can't really see the advantage of using map method at present to be honest.The new keyword can be used for classes,but accessing certificationarray for example does not seem possible from a different JS file.

Comment: `$.getJson` gets you json data from controller here in script `.arrayMap` will convert the array of objects to proper observable's .please refer docs of ko .  further please feel to make a new post of other query many can share there view . cheers