# Populate Multi-select list from Ajax in Knockout

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an editable table based off of the Knockoutjs [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html). I've been trying to populate a multi-select dropdown list from an AJAX call to ASP MVC controller.  I've looked through [this](http://www.romankagan.com/?p=116) example, this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386509/populating-a-dropdown-list-using-knockout-and-jquery-ajax), and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581423/knockoutjs-dynamically-populate-dropdownlist) but am still having issues getting it to work.

Here's the html:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: users' class="table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td><input class='required number form-control' maxlength="9" stringlength="9" data-bind='value: id, uniqueName: true' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required form-control' data-bind='value: firstName' /></td>
                    <td><input class='required form-control' data-bind='value: lastName' /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select data-bind="options: MAMUserGroupsListOptions, selectedOptions: MAMSelectedGroup">
                            <!--dropdown list goes here-->
                        </select>

                    </td>

                    <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeUser'>Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Here's the javascript for the knockout portion:

```
    var UserModel = function (users) {
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray(users);



    //add user
    self.addUser = function () {
        self.users.push({
            id: "",
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            MAMUserGroupsListOptions: "", 
            MAMUserGroups: ""
        });
    };

    //remove user
    self.removeUser = function (user) {
        self.users.remove(user);
    }; 

var viewModel = new UserModel([
    {
        id: ko.observable(""), firstName: ko.observable(""), lastName: ko.observable(""),
        MAMUserGroupsListOptions: ko.observable(),//this is where I need to populate
        MAMSelectedGroups: ko.observable(),//this is the result of the multiselect

    }
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here's the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MAMUserGroupsList()
        {
            var MAMUserGroupsListOptions = db.MAMUserGroupsListModels.Select(x => new {
                MAMUserGroupName = x.MAMUserGroupName
            }).ToList();

            return Json(MAMUserGroupsListOptions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }
```

When the controller is called via AJAX, this is what returns:

```
{MAMUserGroupName: "MAMGroup1"}, {MAMUserGroupName: "MAMGroup2"}, etc...
```

I'm trying to get the multi-select dropdown to have "MAMGroup1", MAMGroup2, etc.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this- any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It returns an array of objects?

Comment: Sorry, I'm bit new to Javascript.  When I write it to the console it technically looks like:
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
MAMUserGroupName
:
"MAMGroup1"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) the array of objects to extract the one value of interest. If you start with your result in a variable named ajaxResult,

```
MAMUserGroupsListOptions(ajaxResult.map(obj => obj.MAMUserGroupName));
```

will assign the values to your observable array. Or if the value is available to you when you're creating your viewmodel,

```
MAMUserGroupsListOptions: ko.observable(ajaxResult.map(obj => obj.MAMUserGroupName))
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing where you meant, did you leave out the colon?  
MAMUserGroupsListOptions: (ajaxResult.map(obj => obj.MAMUserGroupName));

Comment: No, you assign a value to an observable by passing it as an argument. I'm assuming you have created your viewmodel before the ajax result is available. See updated answer.